# How to get results of a TQuery en Delphi?

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi

**DataBase**

When I run the following query in a database:

```
SELECT T.ID
FROM TABLA T
WHERE ID=3
```

Result:

```
No rows returned
```

Now I try show message in Delphi say "The record not exist".

In the form I have a component TQuery call qValidacion successfully connected with database Oracle 11g.

**Try 1**

```
procedure TfPrueba.ButtonAceptarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    qValidacion.Close;
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('SELECT T.ID');
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('FROM TABLA T');
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('WHERE ID=3');
    qValidacion.Open;
    qValidacion.First;
    if (not qValidacion.Eof) then 
        begin
             ShowMessage('The record not exist'); //It Should display the message, but does not show
        end;
    qValidacion.SQL.Clear;
end;
```

Comment: I don't follow. You have a query that returns no rows. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Have you checked to be sure that there is at least one row in `TABLA` which has `ID = 3`?

Comment: You've written `if (not qValidacion.Eof)...` - you want, however to check if you *are* at `Eof`, not if you *are not* at `Eof`.  The idiomatic way to check this, however, is to examine if `qValidacion.RecordCount = 0`.

Comment: `qValidacion.SQL.Add('SELECT T.ID');` - BAD idea - there may already be something! Either call `SQL.Clear` before the first line, or just call one-liner `SQL.Text := ' SELECT  ... WHERE T.ID=3';`

Comment: @J... - and download all the data to the client, maybe all the table, and overflow the memory ?  the idiomatic way is to call `if qValidation.IsEmpty then ...`

Comment: @Arioch'The Does that really happen?! Or is this something quirky about an Oracle DB?  The record count is returned in the server response to the query, is it not?

Comment: @J... server may wish to do it or it may with not to do it. Sometimes server even does not know how many records there are. Example 1: `Select x,y,z from StoredProcedure(a,b,c)`. Example 2: `Select t.x, t.y from table t where SomeUserDefinedFunction(t.z) < 0` Example 3: we are both connected to the server, and while you being reading the table row by row I keep inserting (and committing) new record into the very same table

Comment: @J... ...or it may just return `-1` - the RecordCount is for ISAM files like DBF and SQL access libraries are not even required to override and implement it :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The That's fair enough, I guess I was just considering a straight query that executes and gets a response reasonably immediately.

Comment: @J... While that indeed might be possible (with its cost) for SNAPSHOT transactions, that CAN NOT be provided to less expensive READ COMMITTED transactions: the server can not know the exact TIMING when the client would fetch the last row, and since that the server can not PREDICT FUTURE and issue warranties that until that YET UNKNOWN moment in future when the last row be fetched there DEFINITELY WOULD NOT BE some new extra records inserted from some concurrent transaction. That is not about queries complexity, that is about transactioning model principal properties.

Comment: @J... see... What for us slow protein-based humans is "reasonably immediately" for computers is millions of CPU commands :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, I understand.  At the same time, you're not going to sit for infinity executing `.IsEmpty` over and over in case it changed between the time you executed the check and displayed it to the screen.  I take your point, in any case.  A time-efficient returned record count is not universally guaranteed for all types of queries on all databases (although it *is* returned for some types of queries on some databases).

Comment: @J by definition `.IsEmpty = .BOF and .EOF` - it was introduced either in Delphi 6 or Delphi 87. There was no such function in Delphi 5. So there is no infinity, the `TDataSet` after being opened automatically fetches the first row - kind of calling `.First`. If the row is fetched - then the dataset is not empty. Maybe it has that single row, or maybe a million - but not zero. However, if there is nothing to fetch, then end-of-query reached, cursor closed, and nothing more would be read EVEN if someone inserted them. It is the process of fetching BEFORE .EOF that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if they are any record in your Query don't use the qValidacion.EOF but qValidacion.IsEmpty

```
if (qValidacion.IsEmpty) then 
begin
  ShowMessage('The record not exist'); 
end;
```

The EOF Function is here for returning true when you reach the end of a DataSet. Example:

```
qValidacion.First;
while not qValidacion.eof do
begin
 // do Something with the current record.
 qValidacion.next
end;
```

Edit1: Using IsEmpty is indeed more clean. Thanks to Arioch 'The

Comment: `RecordCount` is bad idea for SQL. It either would be not implemented and return -1, or would be implemented and copy ALL the data from server to client, if there would be enough memory.  One has to call `TDataSet.IsEmpty` instead

Comment: It Works, but with "if (qValidacion.RecordCount = 0) then "